# My body animation in my push menu is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML: im not sure if the problem is here but the links to jquery work since when i remove the body animations from jquery the animation of the menu workss perfectly. But it doesnt go back or push the body since i removed that part from my js code... I cant seem to see what the problem is with the body and close tags and events in my jquery. Would you please check it out for me Id be eternally gratefulllll im exhausted searching for the bug.

```js
// jQuery:seems to work when i remove the body animations or in other words leave the menu animations

var main = function(){
  $('.icon-menu').click(function(){

    $('.menu').animate({
      left:'0px'
    },350);

    $('body').animate({
      left:'290px'
    },350);

    $('.close').click(function(){
      $('.menu').animate({
        left:'-290px'
      },350);

      $('body').animate({
        left:'0px'
      },350);
    });
  };

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
.menu {
  height:50%;
  width:285px;
  left:-290px;
  position:fixed;
  color:#000000;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius:10px;
  top: 5%;
}

.menu ul {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(99,99,102,.5);
  border-opacity-top:0.5;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right:30px;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #636366;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity:0.5;
  cursor: pointer;

}

.menu li:hover{
  opacity:1.0;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4); 
}

.close{
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.close:hover{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);

}

.jumbotron{
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

}

.icon-menu {
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left:20px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width:80px;
  opacity:0.5;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

.icon-menu:hover{
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  opacity:1;
}

.icon-menu i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

html,body{
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400;300'rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<img style="position:absolute; left:430px" src="Pumpkin5.jpg">

<div class='hol'>
  <link href="Pumpkin Box.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="close">
      <img src="close.png"/>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Help</li>
      <li>Blog</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="icon-menu">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      Menu
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Leave the body alone, setup a wrapping div, and animate that instead.  Might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to animate the margin-left of the body ?

```
$('body').animate({
  marginLeft:'290px'
},350);
```

Comment: The animating margin alone worked but when i applied it to close the menu it stopped working altogether. Try it and you'll see.